# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerBo' is defined

Tags: spring, aop

I have doing exercise on spring aop
I have define my spring-bean.xml file that contains defination for all bean 
It is also in the project classpath
But I get thr runtime exception NoSuchBeanDefinationException
What is the issue?not getting 
Here is my code in App.java

```
public class App 
{
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
       ApplicationContextappContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:resources/Spring-Customer.xml");
       System.out.println("ApplicationContext:"+appContext);
       CustomerBo customer=(CustomerBo)appContext.getBean("customerBo");
       customer.addCustomer();
     }
}
```

Here is the content in my Spring-Customre.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="customerBo" class="com.kishor.customer.bo.Impl.CustomerBoImpl" />

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.kishor.aspect.LoggingAspect" />

</beans>
```

HERE IS MY STACK TRACE

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customerBo' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at com.kishor.App.main(App.java:18)




HERE IS MY PROJECT STRUCTURE
/ASpectJBased/src
/ASpectJBased/src/main
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/App.java
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/aspect
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/aspect/LoggingAspect.java
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/customer
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/customer/bo
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/customer/bo/CustomerBo.java
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/customer/bo/Impl
/ASpectJBased/src/main/java/com/kishor/customer/bo/Impl/CustomerBoImpl.java
/ASpectJBased/src/main/resources
/ASpectJBased/src/main/resources/Spring-Customer.xml
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of bean definition xml file with its name.

Comment: I have posted the xml file

Comment: Whenever you get an exception and that's what the question is about, post the stack trace. There's a lot of useful information there to help you/us debug the problem. Note: if you're using maven, the `resources`  is not need in the path. Everything in it gets put in the root of the classpath

Comment: I have using maven still i got this error

Comment: Here is my stack trace

Comment: You'll need to provide more info, e.g., file hierarchy in the artifact or classpath at runtime etc.

Comment: I have posted my  project structure details

Comment: Have you ran it without `resources/` in the path (you pass the the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) yet?

Comment: Yes I have run it without resources path

Comment: that is i have write ApplicationContext context=new ClassPAthXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Customer.xml"); still getting the same exception

Comment: That is fine. I can't spot anything wrong. Can you post your pom.xml and your CustomerBo and your CustomerBoImpl class so we can test it out

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you have not fully understood the project structure of an maven project, or make some mistake:

- `src/main/java` contains the sources that needs to be compiled and
- `src/main/resources` contains the resources that must not been compiled.

Both: the compiled source and the resources, are put at the end in the same directory (of course subdirectories will remain)

Therefore a file located at `src/main/resources` will be in the classpath root! This mean **you have to remove the `resources` folder name from your specification from where to load the xml**:

```
ApplicationContextappContext=
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:Spring-Customer.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the XML configuration file and add this line:

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.package"></context:component-scan>`

Answer (score 0):

you can get it to work just by changing your ApplicationContext initialiation to

```
  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Customer.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try below one:

public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
       System.out.println("the configuration file is loaded");
       Student su = context.getBean("student",Student.class);
       su.display();

bean.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
                    
   <bean id = "student" class= "springioc.DpendencyInjection.Student">
   <property name="student_Name" value = "hari_Vakkala"/>   
   <property name="id" value = "12"/>   
   </bean>

</beans>

Make sure you have setter methods for the your properties inside your class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**step1:**
please check your XML file and add the line below.

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.noXML"></context:component-scan>
```

here is simple example may help you:

**XML file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.noXML"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

**Student Class Code:**

```java
package com.spring.noXML;
    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("stu")
public class Student {

}
```

**Main Class Code:**

```java
package com.spring.noXML;
    
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/spring/noXML/hello.xml");
    Student stu1=(Student)context.getBean("stu",Student.class);
    System.out.println(stu1);
  }
}
```